# "Ultimate" naturality of the pullback in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, pullback

In differential geometry, pullback is a useful operation to induce various objects on a manifold to another manifold. Furthermore, pullback is very natural in a sense that it commutes with exterior derivative, Lie derivative, etc.

My question concerns the naturality of pullback in a complicated situation.

Let $M$ be a smooth $m$-manifold. Consider a complicated vector bundle $E$ over $M$. For example, let's say
$$E = C^\infty(M) \oplus \Omega^1(M) \oplus \Omega^1(M) \oplus S^2(T^*M) \oplus \Omega^m(M),$$
where $S^2(T^*M)$ is the space of symmetric rank-2 tensor of $T^*M$. Let $F: E \to \Omega^m(M)$ be a map, not necessarily linear but preserves fibers. One example of $F$ could be
$$F(\phi(p), \omega(p), \tau(p), g(p), \eta(p)) = (\phi(p) + g^{ab}(p) \omega_a(p) \tau_b(p)) \eta(p), \qquad p\in M.$$
After $F$ is given, we consider its integral. More precisely, define a function $S: C^\infty(M) \times \Omega^1(M) \times \Omega^1(M) \times S^2(T^*M) \times \Omega^m(M) \to \mathbb R$, given by
$$S(\phi, \omega, \tau, g, \eta) = \int_M F(\phi(p), \omega(p), \tau(p), g(p), \eta(p)).$$
Here, I slightly abused notation. The RHS actually means
$$\int_M (p \mapsto F(\phi(p), \omega(p), \tau(p), g(p), \eta(p))).$$

Question: Do we have
$$S(f^*\phi, f^*\omega, f^*\tau, f^*g, f^*\eta) = S(\phi, \omega, \tau, g, \eta),$$
whenever $f: M\to M$ is a diffeomorphism?

I suspect that the answer should be yes, due to a sort of "naturality" of the pullback operation. However, I cannot formally prove this result.

Comment: It's not clear to me that your $F$ is well defined, or that the integral here even makes sense. Does $F$ still respect fibers even though it's not linear?

Comment: @D.Brogan Sorry, I should have said that $F$ preserves fibers. I edited the question.

Comment: Okay, I am still unconvinced that the integral makes sense. $F$ is not a function, it is a section of some complicated bundle, so I don't see how the integral should be defined in this case unless, for example, the bundle $\mathrm{Hom}(E,\Omega^m(M))$ is trivial. But in this case $F$ is just a function and the equality holds (assuming $M$ is closed).

Comment: @D.Brogan Well, I cannot see why $F$ is not a function but instead a section. Could you elaborate that statement?

Comment: When I say "function" I mean something of the form $f:M\to\mathbb R.$ Integration on a manifold is reserved for (top degree) differential forms. So when you write $\int_M F,$ presumably you want to mean $\int_M F\cdot \omega_M$ where $\omega_M$ is the volume form of $M.$ This is only still a top form if $F$ is a function $M\to \mathbb R.$ Since you instead have $F:E\to\Omega^m(M),$ it's not really clear to me how you want to define the integral.

Comment: So you need to change $F$ to be a section of $\Omega^m(M)\to M.$ You can do this by precomposing with a section of $E\to M$, but then I don't really see the purpose of factoring through $E$

Comment: @D.Brogan I am confused on your comment: "So when you write $\int_M F$, presumably you want to mean $\int_M F \cdot \omega_M$."

I really mean $\int_M F$ as written in my original post. Note that $F(\phi(p), \omega(p), \tau(p), g(p), \eta(p))$ is already a top form, since the definition involves $\eta(p) \in \Omega^m(M)$ in the last factor

Comment: $F$ isn't a top form. It takes values in the same space as top forms, however  a top form is a section $M\to\Omega^m(M).$ I admit I misunderstood your question at first, but the integration still doesn't make sense to me unless you change the domain of $F.$

Comment: @D.Brogan Yes, by itself $F(\phi(p), \omega(p), \tau(p), g(p), \eta(p))$ is not a top form. However, given $\phi, \omega, \tau, g, \eta \in C^\infty(M) \times \Omega^1(M) \times \Omega^1(M) \times S^2(T^*M) \times \Omega^m(M)$, the map
$$p \mapsto  F(\phi(p), \omega(p), \tau(p), g(p), \eta(p))$$
is a section $M \to \Omega^m(M)$. It is this "section" that is integrated over as can be seen in the definition of $S(\phi, \omega, \tau, g, \eta)$.

Comment: Just for sure, I want to mention that I slightly abused the notation. The expression
$$\int_M F(\phi(p), \omega(p), \tau(p), g(p), \eta(p))$$
in the definition of $S$ really means
$$\int_M (p \mapsto F(\phi(p), \omega(p), \tau(p), g(p), \eta(p))).$$
If this was the source of the confusion, I am really sorry.